# Divergence Theorem Question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

$$\iint\limits_\sum f \ d \sigma = \iiint\limits_S \operatorname{div} \textbf{f} \ dV$$

$$\operatorname{div} \textbf{f}=1+2+3=6$$

After this, we could multiply $6$ by the volume of the sphere $\frac{4}{3} \pi (3)^3$ to get $216 \pi$.

Shouldn't computing the integral give the same answer?

$$6\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}  \int_0^3 \ dr \ d \theta \ d \phi$$

$$=6(3)(2\pi)(2\pi)$$

$$=72 \pi^2$$

Is something wrong in the integral?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several things wrong: in spherical coordinates,
$$\mathrm{d}V=r^2\sin\phi\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\phi\,\mathrm{d}\theta,$$
and the ball centered at $O$ with radius $3$ is represented, in spherical coordinates by
$$\Delta=\bigl\{(r,\phi,\theta)\in\mathbb{R}^3\;\bigm\vert\;0\leq r\leq3,\ 0\leq\phi\leq\pi,\ 0\leq\theta\leq2\pi\bigr\}$$
so that your integral should read as:
$$\iiint_\Delta r^2\sin\phi\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\phi\,\mathrm{d}\theta=\int_0^3r^2\,\mathrm{d}r\int_0^\pi\sin\phi\,\mathrm{d}\phi\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta=9\times2\times2\pi=36\pi.$$
Now, $6\times36\pi=216\pi$ and you're done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.